# Spring's @EntityListeners is throwing an exception when using @Postpersist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, entitylisteners

I have a small test application for testing @EntityListeners functionality. When I run the application I get the following stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.hibernate_envers_test.HibernateEnversTestApplication.main(HibernateEnversTestApplication.java:32)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.hibernate_envers_test.AccountListener.crudLogger(AccountListener.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerCallback.performCallback(ListenerCallback.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.postCreate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPostInsertEventListener.onPostInsert(JpaPostInsertEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.postInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 18 more
```

As you can see it complains about not being able to commit a jpa transaction. Followed by a nullpointer exception whenever I try to use my accountHistoryRepo spring jpa repository interface. I have already checked whether the account pojo argument or the repository instance was null, it wasn't the case. When I replace @PostPersist with @PrePersist the TransactionSystemException no longer appears but I still have that mysterious nullpointer exception to deal with. Next to that I prefer to use PostPersist because I don't want to persist a history object when the actual object on which the history object is based wasn't persisted correctly. Can anyone help me? Below is the code of my test application:

AccountListener

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.example.hibernate_envers_test;

import com.example.pojo.Account;
import com.example.pojo.AccountHistory;
import javax.persistence.PostPersist;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 *
 * @author maurice
 */
@Component
public class AccountListener {

    @Autowired
    AccountHistoryRepo accountHistoryRepo;


    @PostPersist
    public void crudLogger(Account account){
        System.out.println("is account null?: " + account == null);
                System.out.println("is account null?: " + account.getJabberId());
        System.out.println("is accountHistoryrRepo null?: " + accountHistoryRepo);
        if (accountHistoryRepo.count()>=10) accountHistoryRepo.deleteOldestEntry();
        accountHistoryRepo.save(new AccountHistory(account));
    } 
}
```

Account pojo

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AccountListener.class)
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long accountId;

    private String name;

    private boolean isEnabled;

    private boolean isSmartsuppEnabled;

    private String jabberId;

    private double budgetWarningPercentage;

    private boolean isSentBudgetWarning;

    private double budgetAmount;

    private int departmentLevel;

    private int contactId;

    public Long getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public Account setAccountId(Long accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Account setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isIsEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public Account setIsEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isIsSmartsuppEnabled() {
        return isSmartsuppEnabled;
    }

    public Account setIsSmartsuppEnabled(boolean isSmartsuppEnabled) {
        this.isSmartsuppEnabled = isSmartsuppEnabled;
        return this;
    }

    public String getJabberId() {
        return jabberId;
    }

    public Account setJabberId(String jabberId) {
        this.jabberId = jabberId;
        return this;
    }

    public double getBudgetWarningPercentage() {
        return budgetWarningPercentage;
    }

    public Account setBudgetWarningPercentage(double budgetWarningPercentage) {
        this.budgetWarningPercentage = budgetWarningPercentage;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isIsSentBudgetWarning() {
        return isSentBudgetWarning;
    }

    public Account setIsSentBudgetWarning(boolean isSentBudgetWarning) {
        this.isSentBudgetWarning = isSentBudgetWarning;
        return this;
    }

    public double getBudgetAmount() {
        return budgetAmount;
    }
```

accounthistory pojo

```
@Entity(name = "account_history")
public class AccountHistory implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long accountHistoryId;

    private Long accountId;

    private String name;

    private boolean isEnabled;

    private boolean isSmartsuppEnabled;

    private String jabberId;

    private double budgetWarningPercentage;

    private boolean isSentBudgetWarning;

    private double budgetAmount;

    private int departmentLevel;

    private int contactId;

    public AccountHistory(){}

    public AccountHistory(Account account){
        this.accountId = account.getAccountId();
        this.name = account.getName();
        this.isEnabled = account.isIsEnabled();
        this.isSmartsuppEnabled  = account.isIsSmartsuppEnabled();
        this.jabberId = account.getJabberId();
        this.budgetWarningPercentage = account.getBudgetWarningPercentage();
        this.isSentBudgetWarning = account.isIsSentBudgetWarning();
        this.budgetAmount = account.getBudgetAmount();
        this.departmentLevel = account.getDepartmentLevel();
        this.contactId = account.getContactId();    
    }

    public Long getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public AccountHistory setAccountId(Long accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public AccountHistory setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isIsEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public AccountHistory setIsEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isIsSmartsuppEnabled() {
        return isSmartsuppEnabled;
    }

    public AccountHistory setIsSmartsuppEnabled(boolean isSmartsuppEnabled) {
        this.isSmartsuppEnabled = isSmartsuppEnabled;
        return this;
    }

    public String getJabberId() {
        return jabberId;
    }

    public AccountHistory setJabberId(String jabberId) {
        this.jabberId = jabberId;
        return this;
    }

    public double getBudgetWarningPercentage() {
        return budgetWarningPercentage;
    }

    public AccountHistory setBudgetWarningPercentage(double budgetWarningPercentage) {
        this.budgetWarningPercentage = budgetWarningPercentage;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isIsSentBudgetWarning() {
        return isSentBudgetWarning;
    }

    public AccountHistory setIsSentBudgetWarning(boolean isSentBudgetWarning) {
        this.isSentBudgetWarning = isSentBudgetWarning;
        return this;
    }

    public double getBudgetAmount() {
        return budgetAmount;
    }

    public AccountHistory setBudgetAmount(double budgetAmount) {
        this.budgetAmount = budgetAmount;
        return this;
    }

    public int getDepartmentLevel() {
        return departmentLevel;
    }

    public AccountHistory setDepartmentLevel(int departmentLevel) {
        this.departmentLevel = departmentLevel;
        return this;
    }

    public int getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }

    public AccountHistory setContactId(int contactId) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
        return this;
    }
}



    public Account setBudgetAmount(double budgetAmount) {
        this.budgetAmount = budgetAmount;
        return this;
    }

    public int getDepartmentLevel() {
        return departmentLevel;
    }

    public Account setDepartmentLevel(int departmentLevel) {
        this.departmentLevel = departmentLevel;
        return this;
    }

    public int getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }

    public Account setContactId(int contactId) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
        return this;
    }
}
```

AccountHistoryRepo

```
@Repository
public interface AccountHistoryRepo extends JpaRepository<AccountHistory,Long> {
    @Query("DELETE FROM account_history p WHERE p.accountHistoryId = (SELECT MIN(p.accountHistoryId) FROM account_history p)")
    public void deleteOldestEntry();
}
```

AccountRepo

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account,Long> {

}
```

main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HibernateEnversTestApplication implements ApplicationContextAware  {

    private static ApplicationContext ac;

//    @Autowired
//    AccountRepository accountRepo;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HibernateEnversTestApplication.class, args);
                AccountRepository accountRepo = ac.getBean(AccountRepository.class);
                //Account account = accountRepo.findOne(1003L);
                Account account = new Account();
                account.setBudgetAmount(6666.4)
                        .setBudgetWarningPercentage(66666.2)
                        .setContactId(3333)
                        .setDepartmentLevel(44444)
                        .setIsEnabled(true)
                        .setIsSentBudgetWarning(false)
                        .setIsSmartsuppEnabled(true)
                        .setJabberId("en dit is aanpassing 4")
                        .setName("henk");
                accountRepo.save(account);
    }

            @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.ac = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

root config

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")})
@ComponentScan//(basePackages={"repository"})
@EnableJpaRepositories//(basePackages={"repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RootConfig {

  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
  private String dataBaseUrl;
  @Value("${spring.datasource.driver}")
  private String driver;
  @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
  private String userName;
  @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
  private String password;
  @Value("${spring.datasource.strategy}")
  private String strategy;

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource seedDataSource(){
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(driver);
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(dataBaseUrl); 
    hikariConfig.setUsername(userName);
    hikariConfig.setPassword(password);

    hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");

    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.cachePrepStmts", "true");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.useServerPrepStmts", "true");

    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

    return dataSource;
}    

  @Bean
  JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
  }  

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, 
                                                                JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter){
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy","org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy");
  props.put("org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp", "true");
  props.put("org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision","true");
  props.put("org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag","true");
  props.put("org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete", "true");
  props.put("hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister", "true");

  entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
  entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
  entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.pojo");
  entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(props);
  return entityManagerFactory;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    adapter.setShowSql(false);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    return adapter;
}  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you made the entity listener a @Component, what JPA uses is actually just an instance of the class and is not a spring managed bean. That's why you're getting a NullPointerException. The `accountHistoryRepo` will always be null.

Comment: an instance of what class, the AccountListener class? I'm reading in my hibernate book that an EntityListener has no constructor and is always stateless, the JPA engine automatically creates and destroys it. Is this what you mean? When I print out accountHistoryRepo == null then it print false, not true. So it cannot be null. Should I be using EntityListener for what i'm trying to achieve or should I seek an alternative.

Comment: The NullReferenceException is quite clearly the cause. It's not mysterious and it's not happening after. It's happening first and it's the cause of the RollbackException which in turn is the cause of the TransactionSystemException. What code is located in AccountListener line 38?

Comment: JPA does not know anything about Spring and ignores the @Autowired annotation so your accountHistoryRepo is always null in the entity listener.

Comment: thx for the answers Strelok, I am going to try to achieve what I want using Spring Data Rest' s AbstractEntityListener class